# Python os chdir error with folder starting with a number Windows folder

Tags: python, windows, path, backslash

Spent 3 hours looking how to use `os.chdir`, I got an `OSError` when running this code:

```
dir1= "D:\_devs\Python01\project\03-Connect_\PyBind"

os.chdir(dir1)
```

> OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: `'D:\\_devs\\Python01\\project\x03-Connect_\\PyBind\\examples'`

The definition of `dir1` cannot be modified (because I want to keep copy/paste from windows folder (ex by using `r'<string>` or slash)

But the `dir1` variable can be modified by string manipulation.

Why `\x`  is generated ?

EDIT2 (leasing space remove):

```
    dir1 = r"D:\_devs\Python01\project\03-Connect_Java_CPP_Excel\PyBindGen\examples"

     dir2= os.path.abspath(dir1)

    os.chdir(dir1)
```

still have the error...

Comment: `dir1` doesn't seem to have the initial `\`

Comment: `\0` is getting translated to `\x0`. You need either `r"D:` etc or `\\03`

Comment: If you mean that you want to paste a Windows path into your Python script as a literal string then you will need to either make it a raw string, or backslash escape the backslashes in the path. BTW, what do you mean by "anti slash"?

Comment: I still have the error: 
dir1 = r" D:\_devs\Python01\project\03-Connect_Java_CPP_Excel\PyBindGen\examples"

dir2= os.path.abspath(dir1)

os.chdir(dir1)

Comment: Your 2nd attempt should have worked as far as I can tell. I see this is not what you asked for, but it may unveil a typo in the path. I think in not all cases you would be able to recover the original path anyway (e.g. "c:\x41\x42" == "c:AB"). Further from adding "r" or doubling the backslashes/replacing them with forward slashes, your conventional options include moving this setting to an environment variable or a separate configuration file, then it can be edited there as you like. I suggest you consider these, too, if this is part of a larger thing you are planning to create.

Comment: Using `r"D:\_devs\Python01\project\03-Connect_Java_CPP_Excel\PyBindGen\examples"` should not cause `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` (WinError 123). It's a valid path that's within the Windows 260-character limit (`MAX_PATH`), but it may not exist or may be inaccessible. Are you getting some other error now?

Comment: Yes, with the code should fine, thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You can try string-escape and replacing:

```
def norm(pth):
    pth = pth.encode("string-escape").replace("\\x", "/")
    return pth.replace("\\\\", "/")
```

You would probably need a regex for a more robust approach but it should work for your example strings:

```
In [77]: dir1 = "D:\_devs\Python01\project\03-Connect_\PyBind"

In [78]: norm(dir1)
Out[78]: 'D:/_devs/Python01/project/03-Connect_/PyBind'
```

For python3 try:

```
def norm(pth):
    pth = pth.encode("unicode-escape").replace(b"\\x", b"/")
    return pth.replace(b"\\\\", b"/").decode("utf-8")
```

For paths with no hex it should just return the string with just any backslashes changed to `/`:

```
In [30]: dir1 = "D:\_devs\Python01\project\Connect_\PyBind"

In [31]: norm(dir1)
Out[31]: 'D:/_devs/Python01/project/Connect_/PyBind'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have LookupError: unknown encoding: string-escape

Comment: So you are using python3?

Comment: Yes,..3.4, This is 2.7 solution ?
Wondering if 2.7 will stay forever in Python....

Comment: @quantCode, 2.7 is supported until 2020 and will be around for long after, try the edit for python3

Comment: I may disagree. Theoretically what you ask for may be impossible to do.

Once you have subdirectories like "x41", a path containing it will translate to something weird, since "c:\x41\x42" translates to "c:AB", as 41 is the code of A in hexadecimal, 42 is for B. Now you may see converting such results back is ambiguous (different inputs get converted to the same output, i.e. how do you find out if it was c:\x41B or c:\x41\x42 originally?). Do look at the escape sequences to understand why. https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: @brezniczky, if you want to address the OP, do so as a comment under the question.

Comment: (OK, thanks - I think the above was informative to the both of you, due to potential infeasibility, but will continue above.)

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: thank you for your expertise.

Maybe, Python ORG should spent time to reconcile 2 and 3 rather doing new features....(adding the hours of double coding....)

Comment: @quantCode, no worries, like I said in the answer you would have to add more logic if you wanted a more robust solution, if you know the general structure of your paths you can use a regex to be more specific but in either case there is no magic bullet. As far as 2 and 3 goes, there would be as much work if not more getting python3 to be compatible with python2, I do think 3 is a major improvement though.

Comment: FYI, you cannot use slash in place of backslash in various places, such as the command line of some programs and all native NT paths. The latter includes ``\\?\`` extended paths as well named kernel objects that need to be global, e.g. `Global\SomeEventObject` (this is actually a path in which `Global` is a symbolic link in the current session's `BaseNamedObjects` directory to the root `\BaseNamedObjects`). In native paths, slash is just another character. For Python 3, use the `pathlib` module; it lets you use slash but normalizes properly to backslash.

Comment: @eryksun, it is by no means a robust solution but there are not a great deal of other options bar using string-escape, a regex would be needed to make sure the correct parts were replaced and even then there is a lot of ambiguity in what you could consider the correct output, I have never really used windows so  if you feel there is any improvements related to windows feel free to edit

Comment: The problem with backslash is due to string literals, so the solution is to make sure to use raw literals or to escape backslash by doubling it, or to use slash and then normalize to backslash via `pathlib` or `os.path.normpath`.

Comment: @eryksun,  if the OP was creating the strings that would be easy, they were  trying to do it after being passed the strings  trying to double up the backslashes with the OP's example input would not work either that is why  string/unicode-escape is used. Calling `os.path.normpath` after doing the work in the answer would be possible though.

Comment: I read in the question that quantCode wants *"to keep copy/paste from windows folder"*. What stops quantCode from pasting it into a raw string literal? Without that, in Python 3 it's going to blow up in `SyntaxError` given improper `\u`, `\U`, and `\N` sequences, and even without getting an error, this cannot be reversed since it's not a one-to-one mapping.

Comment: @eryksun, I read *The definition of dir1 cannot be modified*.  I presumed the rest was misworded as they also explicitly mention not putting an `r`, if they were doing it manually there would be no question

Comment: Backslash is only a problem for string literals as input or in source files. However the string literal is getting created, it's the source literal that needs to be modified, not the string object.

Comment: @eryksun, that is not what he original question was about, if it was about how the string was being created I would not be suggesting string-escape